# How to sum 2 different column and sum it for different row

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

how to calculate menu_price * menu_quantity and total for all row
here my code, this one only for one column, and without multiple with menu_quantity. when you see the table, you can guess that I want calculate total cost

```
string stmt = "SELECT SUM(menu_price) FROM cart Where email=@email";

try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
   ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Session["email"].ToString());
            con.Open();
            int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return count;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    lbltotalitemcart.Text = e.ToString();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is neither a C# question or an asp.net question, its an SQL question

Comment: Also: one user might generally have more than one session (say in different browsers), each with it's own cart as they try to compare different options. You should use a session key rather than e-mail address to distinguish these.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the multiplication within the `SUM()`:

```
SELECT SUM(menu_price * menu_quantity) FROM cart WHERE email=@email
```